# I don't understand why this loop terminates the way it does

Tags: python, loops, cx-oracle

```
checkSql = 'SELECT userid FROM bs_members WHERE userid = :checkUser'
doesUserExist = False
while True:
    doesUserExist = False
    newUser.userID = ga.getInput('Enter userID: ', "\w+$")
    checkUserID = ds.execute(checkSql,checkUser=newUser.userID)
    for row in ds:
        if row == checkUserID:
            doesUserExist = True
            print 'That user name is already in use.  Please enter a new username.'
            break
    if doesUserExist == False:
        break
    else:
        continue
```

I am using the `cx_Oracle` module with Python 2.7.  I am trying to prompt the user to enter a userID.  The program will then check if the userID already exists and if it does prompt the user for a different userID.  The execute method is a helper method that uses the execute method from cx_Oracle to interact with the Oracle database.  The getInput method prompts the user for input that is then checked against the regular expression.

I know I have this wrong but I believe the `while` loop starts the first action that is taken is the user is prompted for a userID.  Then the userID is checked against the database.  The `for` loop starts and checks if the row returned by `ds.execute()` is the same as the userID provided by the user.  If it is the user is told to use another user name and the `break` exits the `for` loop.  The `if` statement then checks if a user exists and if it doesn't it breaks the `while` loop.  If not then the `while` loop iterates so the user is prompted to enter a non-existent userID.

What happens is the user is prompted for the userID then none of the checking ever appears to happen to the user and the program moves on to the next piece of code.  What am I missing here?  I have included a [link](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html#Cursor.execute) to the docs for `execute()`.  The execute method in the above code is part of the following helper method:

```
def execute(self, statement, **parameters):
    if parameters is None:
        self._curs.execute(statement)
    else:
        self._curs.execute(statement,parameters)
```

If I need to provide more information let me know.

edit: I forgot the line `doesUserExist = False` immediately after the beginning of the `while` loop so I added that.

Comment: How does the current behavior deviate from your expected behavior?

Comment: Um, shouldn't you just be using `COUNT()` instead and checking the resultant value?

Comment: `if doesUserExist == False: break` ? Please explain the logic here.

Comment: @Lasse: The "while" should loop until an unused user ID is given. The if sentence is the loop's exit condition at the moment. At the "break" command, execution jumps out of the "while" loop.

Comment: So, if the user inputs a username in use, at which point does it ever get back to false?

Comment: Never, I posted an answer for that.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: That still won't fix the problem.  The issue is that the loop is exiting no matter what execute(...) returns.  So if the user inputs a userID that already exists the loop exits.

Comment: @Blender: The expected behavior is as follows: if a user inputs an existing userID the program will scream and require the user to choose a different userID.  The current behavior is as follows: no matter what userID is chosen the program exits the loop and continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your custom `execute` method doesn't return anything meaning that `checkUserID` in your code will be `None`.

Furthermore, what you're interested in is if there's at least one row returned by the query. If there are none then the userID should be available.

The docs say that calling `.fetchone()` returns `None` if no more rows are available. You can use that.

```
checkSql = 'SELECT userid FROM bs_members WHERE userid = :checkUser'
while True:
    newUser.userID = ga.getInput('Enter userID: ', "\w+$")
    ds.execute(checkSql,checkUser=newUser.userID)
    if ds.fetchone() is None:
        # This userID is available.
        break
    else:
        print 'That user name is already in use.  Please enter a new username.'
```

I'm assuming here that `ds` is an instance of `Cursor`, or subclass thereof.

Comment: +1 for a good answer and making the function look pretty tidy.

Comment: This is the answer.  Thank you yak.  This happened because I was assuming the `execute` method was returning a value and it wasn't.  I need to work on my assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

At least you should have line `doesUserExist = False` at the beginning of the while loop. Otherwise, if user enters an existing ID once then it will keep looping forever.